# Delete XML Child Node Element in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I have this xml, I want to insert it into temp table including the values inside `<salesorpurchase>` node in a single row. Is this possible?

Or can you tell me how to remove the `<SalesOrPurchase>` without removing its inner text`?

```
<ItemServiceRet> 
    <ListID>80000012-1302270176</ListID> 
    <EditSequence>1302270195</EditSequence>
    <Name>2nd Floor Shop</Name>
    <FullName>2nd Floor Shop</FullName> 
    <IsActive>true</IsActive>
    <SalesOrPurchase>
        <Price>0.00</Price>
        <AccountRef> 
            <ListID>800000B3-1302260225</ListID>
            <FullName>Rent Income:Rent income 2ND FL:2nd Floor Shops</FullName> 
        </AccountRef>
    </SalesOrPurchase>
</ItemServiceRet> 
<ItemServiceRet> 
    <ListID>80000002-1277187768</ListID> 
    <EditSequence>1463398389</EditSequence>
    <Name>VAT 16%</Name> 
    <FullName>VAT 16%</FullName>
    <IsActive>true</IsActive> 
    <SalesOrPurchase>
        <PricePercent>16.00</PricePercent> 
        <AccountRef>
            <ListID>6B0000-1224749077</ListID> 
            <FullName>Vat account</FullName> 
        </AccountRef> 
    </SalesOrPurchase> 
</ItemServiceRet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Try following query to insert data from every `ItemServiceRet` element into one row (in this case, because there are two `ItemServiceRet` elements two rows will be inserted):

```
DECLARE @XmlData XML = N'
<ItemServiceRet> 
    <ListID>80000012-1302270176</ListID> 
    <EditSequence>1302270195</EditSequence>
    <Name>2nd Floor Shop</Name>
    <FullName>2nd Floor Shop</FullName> 
    <IsActive>true</IsActive>
    <SalesOrPurchase>
        <Price>0.00</Price>
...
</ItemServiceRet>'

SELECT  ListID          = y.XmlCol.value('(ListID)[1]', 'VARCHAR(19)'),
        EditSequence    = y.XmlCol.value('(EditSequence)[1]', 'INT'),
        -- ...
        Price           = y.XmlCol.value('(SalesOrPurchase/Price)[1]', 'NUMERIC(9,2)'),
        PricePercent    = y.XmlCol.value('(SalesOrPurchase/PricePercent)[1]', 'NUMERIC(9,2)'),
        ListID2         = y.XmlCol.value('(SalesOrPurchase/AccountRef/ListID)[1]', 'VARCHAR(19)')
INTO    #Items
FROM    (VALUES (@XmlData)) x(XmlCol)/*or @XmlData.nodes*/
CROSS APPLY x.XmlCol.nodes(N'ItemServiceRet') y(XmlCol)

/*
Results:
(2 row(s) affected)
*/
```

This solution is using two XML methods: [nodes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) (shred XML into many rows) and value (it extract one value from current node/element).

2) Second solution is *"deleting"* the `SalesOrderHeader` node thus:

```
SELECT  x.XmlCol.query('
    for $i in (ItemServiceRet)
        return
            <ItemServiceRet>
                <ListID>{$i/ListID/text()}</ListID> 
                <IsActive>{$i/IsActive/text()}</IsActive>
                <Price>{$i/SalesOrPurchase/Price/text()}</Price>
                <PricePercent>{$i/SalesOrPurchase/PricePercent/text()}</PricePercent>
                <AccountRef>
                    <ListID>{$i/SalesOrPurchase/AccountRef/ListID/text()}</ListID>  
                    <FullName>{$i/SalesOrPurchase/AccountRef/FullName/text()}</FullName> 
                </AccountRef>
            </ItemServiceRet>
') AS NewXmlCol
FROM    (SELECT (@XmlData)) x(XmlCol)
```

Comment: Don't forget to replace data types, max lenght, precision and scale used in my example with the proper values.